# Need to pass local array to a function on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am writing a menu system and I need to call a function when the user clicks on a specific row. I am using new function to pass the div that called the function as well as the row the user clicked on. All well and good until I try to pass a local array to the function. If I do the following:

```
for (i=0;i<tmpdropnumber;i++){
    var dv=document.getElementById(id+i);
    dv.style.cursor="pointer";  
    dv.onmouseover = new Function('dropover'+"('" + id + "','" + i + "')");
    dv.onmouseout = new Function('dropout'+"('" + id + "','" + i + "')");
    dv.onclick = new Function('dropclick'+"('" + id + "','" + i + "','"+tmparray1+"','"+tmparray2+"')");
}
```

As you'd expect the arrays are passed as strings. I could rebuild the arrays in the function but that seems inelegant.

if I try the following:

```
for (i=0;i<tmpdropnumber;i++){
    var dv=document.getElementById(id+i);
    dv.style.cursor="pointer";  
    dv.onmouseover = new Function('dropover'+"('" + id + "','" + i + "')");
    dv.onmouseout = new Function('dropout'+"('" + id + "','" + i + "')");
    dv.onclick = new Function('dropclick'+"('" + id + "','" + i + "',"+tmparray1+","+tmparray2+")");
}
```

Trying to pass the arrays it crashes. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I am using jquery in my code so wither a javascript or jquery solution would be fine.

Comment: Because it is using toString() when it is building the string.

Comment: in one easy word: [json](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: I'm making a custome drop down type menu. I add a bunch of divs using a loop and attach the onclick functions when they are created. Therefore when a user clicks my function knows which row was clicked on. Always works with string just can't pass arrays (or objects) as new function only seems to pass strings.

Comment: Bondye? json? What in the world would that solve.

Comment: I do use JSON a lot in my code but for complex reasons I really need arrays at this part

Comment: Epascarello - I see where you're coming from. Will try to rebuild the new function as strings and arrays and see if it works

Comment: @epascarello: You could actually stringify the array in the function call and parse it in the `dropclick` function.

Comment: @Amberlamps and what happens if the content in the array holds objects? That will not work.

Comment: @epascarello: Yeah, but if we have a array of literals we are good. Still, I do not approve a JSON solution at all. Besides what you were already pointing out, we have to serialize and deserialize an object without actually having to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use new Function.

You are having problems because when the string is being built, the array is being turned into a string.

basic idea to get around the toString()

```
for (i=0;i<tmpdropnumber;i++){
    var dv=document.getElementById(id+i);
    dv.style.cursor="pointer";
    (function(id, i){  
        dv.onmouseover = function(){ dropover(id,i); };
        dv.onmouseout = function(){ dropout(id,i); };
        dv.onclick = function(){ dropclick(id,i, tmparray1, tmparray2); };
    })(id,i);
}
```

But in reality there is no need to pass in an object, id.

You can always use `this` to get the current row and there is rowIndex on the table. Heck you can have one event handler on the table and use handlers on the table/tbody to capture the bubbling and use target/srcElement.

Comment: sorry. didn't explain - I'm not actually using a table. I know how to get row references for that. I need pixel perfect precision so am building a table like structure from divs

Comment: Thanks for this - looks like it is exactly what I need. I don't really understand anonymous function wrappers. Why are my variables id and i referenced after function and at the end but not the arrays?

Comment: The function that is wrapped around the event handlers forces i to not hold a reference, but rather use the value. The id probably does not have to be there either.

Comment: Id is just a variable ref to my div. don't think it needs to be there either. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
dv.onclick = new Function('dropclick'+"('" + id + "','" + i + "','"+tmparray1+"','"+tmparray2+"')");
```

try

```
dv.onclick = function() {
    dropclick(id, i, tmparray1, tmparray2);
};
```

**Edit**

Wrap your declaration in a anonymous function:

```
(function(id, i) {
    dv.onclick = function() {
        dropclick(id, i, tmparray1, tmparray2);
    };
} (id, i));
```

Comment: This doesn't pick up the correct reference to i at run time. i is always shown at it's last value.

Comment: Loving the look of that - will try and let you know